# Enable C++ support ARMCC compiler

Tags: c++, keil

I'm setting up a basic project in Keil (V5). I want to use C++ in my project. I'm using the ARMCC compiler.

I created a simple class CTest. But it seems that my project settings/compiler doesn't support C++. C code compiles well, but the keyword 'class' is not recognized.

[image: screenshot]

Build log:

[image: build log]

Is there a special setting to enable C++ features?

Comment: Did you tried to call your file main.cpp ?

Comment: That fix works, thanks:) But my systick function cannot be in main.cpp, so i had to move it to a separate C file.

Comment: If you can't have systick in a .cpp due to C++ name mangling, you should be able to put it in your .cpp if you use extern "C" in the definition, e.g. extern "C" int systick( ... ) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to make a project and compiling C++ worked fine. However, it will fail if you try to insert code into a C file. (i.e. with a .c extension.) Make sure your file has a .cpp extension.

Edit:

And in your case, a .h is fine, but if it includes C++ definitions you can't include it in .c files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the --cpp to enable compiler support.
I've read armcc user guide, and it supports a subset of c++11.

Add:

I don't think a header file have a language type.
It's used only when it's included by a source file.

Answer (score 0):

under project options c/c++ tab for misc controls use --CPP

it points to cpp compiler

Answer (score 0):

You must add Options For Target section->C/C++ Section
Misc   --cpp   [Keil C++ Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYp6U.png)

Answer (score 0):

In *project->manage->project*, items->folders extensions add `*.hpp` as a c++ file extension and rename header files to `*.hpp`. That should work.